# Enable autocorrect/spellcheck on macOS SwiftUI TextField

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

When using SwiftUI's `TextField` on Big Sur, it seems that `TextField` does not correctly show spelling mistakes or use autocorrect. This is in contrast to `TextEditor`, which seems to behave correctly.

**I've tried adding `disableAutocorrection(false)`, which seemed to have no effect.**

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var headline = "Headline"
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Headline", text: $headline)
                .disableAutocorrection(false)
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .disableAutocorrection(false)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

In the above image, I would expect "Headlineasdfasdf" to be underlined in red as the misspelled words in the `TextEditor` below are. I would've also expected the `TextField` to change my `--` to a long dash as I typed, as it did in the `TextEditor`.

Is there any way to get this behavior with the native SwiftUI `TextField` without having to wrap `NSTextField` in `NSViewRepresentable`?

*(Built with Xcode 13.0 and tested on macOS 11.3)*

Comment: I don't have Big Sur anymore, but for your info, it sort of works in Monterey in TextField, but not well. You often have to type a 
space, then go back, then the autocorrection starts.
eg; typing `Headlinez` then a space, then backspace.

Comment: @workingdog thanks -- good to know that there's at least hope in the future.